# Catbox (Complete Automotive Tests in a Box): No available device

Tags: cts, aaos

When I run the CATBOX command, I always get the following error

```
Android Complete Automotive Test in a Box 1.0 (9012788)
Use "help" or "help all" to get more information on running commands.
01-18 13:42:41 E/adb: * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
01-18 13:42:44 E/adb: * daemon started successfully
Using commandline arguments as starting command: [run, catbox-performance-cold-app-start-up-dialer, --serial, 0123456789ABCDEF]
01-18 13:42:46 D/CommandScheduler: No available device matching all the config's requirements for cmd id 1.
```

The problem shows that there is no available device. I have confirmed that ADB can capture the device, the ANDROID version also corresponds, and the environment has been established according to the file instructions. Is there anything that may be missed?

I followed the official instructions in this article, but the error still occurred.

https://source.android.com/docs/automotive/tools/catbox?hl=zh-tw

Sometimes the following error occurs,

```
x$ ./tools/catbox-tradefed run commandAndExit catbox_function_account_setting --serial emulator-5554
==================
Android Complete Automotive Test in a Box 1.0 (9012787)
Use "help" or "help all" to get more information on running commands.
01-23 10:30:24 E/DeviceMonitor: Cannot reach ADB server, attempting to reconnect.
Using commandline arguments as starting command: [run, commandAndExit, catbox_function_account_setting, --serial, emulator-5554]
Failed to run command: com.android.tradefed.config.ConfigurationException: Can not find local config catbox_function_account_setting.
01-23 10:30:25 V/LogRegistry: Saved log to /tmp/tradefed_global_log_6156147072514484715.txt

01-23 10:30:25 I/CommandScheduler: All done
```